# xml to textboxes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am building a web application where I have to read some values from the config file which I am assuming as nothing but an XML file. So in this process I am able to read the XML document using

```
XDocument config = XDocument.Load("\\path\to\example.exe.config");
```

Now I have a textbox in my web page. I want to get a specific value into that textbox where the user can edit and update that value in the textbox.

Can any one guide me to the solution?

Using C#, Linq to XML, Asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have an `XDocument`, so you can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to query it for the value. Put that in the textbox when the page is rendered. Of course when you POST the value you'll have to load the file a second time, query the `XDocument` again, and then update the XML element with the new value before saving.

Comment: Can you give me some syntax about how to query for a value ? supppose i  have <ConnectionString><add name=" " connectionstring=""/><ConnectionString> from which i want the value of connectionstring.

Comment: `string cs = config.Descendants("ConnectionString").First().Element("add").Attribute("connectionstring").Value;`. That assumes the XML does not use namespaces and the elements do exist always, otherwise the `First()` will throw an error.

Comment: Its working fine.What if i want to have 3 textboxes and do the same thing ?? Do i need to declare 3 different srtings ????